# I need to get 100% accuracy on my training data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I know this is undesirable in most cases, but I have a very niche case where I must achieve 100% accuracy on training data. I do not care about unseen points, I only care about given X points what is the Y value for each point. I will train the model before hand but I must get 100% accuracy guaranteed.

Some knowledge I know about the data:

- The data is always increasing (its sorted).
- It is not increasing at a specific rate, it could be random from point to another.
- The data comes in chunks, I do not have all the data right away.
- I can not store the data at all, the moment I get a chunk, it will be deleted. I can probably temporarily store it before the next data comes but can't store it long.
- Each chunk is roughly about 100MB in size.
- I can store some information about `chunk 1` if needed, such as max, min, average, etc... I can analyze it and store anything from the analytics.

Example:

Assume `chunk 1` arrives at minute 0, then at minute 2 `chunk 2` arrives but `chunk 1` is gone.
Days later I will receive the **exact** same data, 100% the same. I will receive it in the same order and same sized chunks. My goal is to predict the result for each value in the chunk at a 100% accuracy given that the data was seen before.

What I have tried:

1. Obvious solution is to store a mapping between the input and their corresponding values, but again this is impossible because it would require me to store the data when it is impossible for me to store.
2. I used different types of trendlines; But this fails miserably as the error is huge, plus it requires me to create a different trendline for each chunk (I don't mind but not preferred)

As I am researching I cam across `Lagrange Polynomial` which sounded very promising. But with more research I found out that I can not use it because it requires all of the data to already exist before I can "predict" the point I am looking for, which obviously defeats the purpose. Unless I have understood it wrong, or misusing it.

I have been researching but can't find much information since most use cases do not require a a use case where you get 100% on training data, it is usually considered a bad practice because of "overfitting".

I have also tried different things but none worked, so I finally came to the conclusion that maybe I could train an AI model? But really not sure where to start to be able to get 100% accuracy on training data.

I am open to using tensorflow or any other tools. I am basically open for any leads to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you hash the chunk and simply recall the truth you previously associated with that hash.  Seems to lead to 100% recall to me.

Comment: What *can* you store? “Anything about analytics” is rather meaningless, since the empirical distribution is also analytics and it would mean storing all the data.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is that you need to [losslessly compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) and retrieve the data. Did you consider any off-the-shelf [caching](https://blog.bytebytego.com/p/a-crash-course-in-caching-part-1) solution? Since you care about “predicting” the seen data, it's about compressing it, and if I were you I’d start with ready data compression algorithms. If they don't compress the data enough, you could try machine learning, but storing machine learning model also needs storage space, and the 100% accurate model  will possibly be one that is complicated, so heavy.

When using machine learning, you could simply fit one model per chunk, so there is no problem with not seeing all the data at once. If you insist on having a single model, it would be more complicated and it would need to be able to distinguish somehow between the chunks (so it doesn't predict chunk 2 for chunk 1). So it might be harder to do, but the model itself could potentially be smaller than the per-chunk models if there are patterns that repeat between the chunks.

But really, start with regular caching and compression. Decent compression algorithms were designed for such purposes and can do miracles.